# C++ Getters and Setters alternatives for Call Stack on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'd like to know if there is a way to inspect the data os this piece of code with a breakpoint in Visual Studio:

```
someClass.someVar = 12;
```

In the same way i would with this one:

```
someClass.SetSomeVar(12);
```

There is a way to know the variable's data without making getters and setters ???

Comment: Define "inspect". If it's a primitive, there isn't anything to inspect really, except the data before and after in the watch window. If the type overloads `operator=` you can just place a breakpoint in there.

Comment: when i said "inspect", i meant when you set a breakpoint on a Set method and on the call stack you can see every line of code that is calling it

Comment: I see. For overloaded `operator=` you place a regular breakpoint. For primitives, see **ilim**s answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller If the class has any attributes that can be modified without using operator=, then overloading that single operator may be insufficient. I'd suggest setting data breakpoints for each attribute of the class/type. It's more tedious, but at least you don't modify the source code.

Comment: @ilim - The class in question which my overload `operator=` is `decltype(someVar)`, not `someClass`

Answer (score 5):

There is a concept called [data breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0(v=vs.90).aspx) that may help you achieve debugging as you stated, without necessarily modifying your code. You may also want to look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621535/what-are-data-breakpoints) on data breakpoints.

However if the type T that *someVar* belongs to is not primitive, the simplest way to achieve the desired result is overloading operator= of that type, and set a simple breakpoint in the scope of that overloaded method.