# How can I set a data breakpoint in a C# program in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I set a data breakpoint in a C# program in Visual Studio 2015?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/621537/156458 says that for C++

> **How to Set a Memory Change Breakpoint**
>
> From the Debug Menu, choose New Breakpoint and click New Data
>   Breakpoint
>
> —or—
>
> in the Breakpoints window Menu, click the New dropdown and choose New
>   Data Breakpoint.

But neither exists in Visual Studio 2015.

Is data breakpoint not supported for C#?

Why is it supported for C++, but not for C#?
Is it technically difficult to implement?

Any way to work around?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't appear to be possible unfortunately: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Edit: It's a much requested feature with some discussion about it: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/6097301-support-data-breakpoints-for-c

Comment: Is it technically difficult to implement? Why is it implemented for C++ but not for C#?

Comment: See my edit, there is much conversation around it.

Comment: @Tim  Likely because C++ natively exposes addresses, and C# doesn't

Comment: any way to work around?

Comment: Maybe, depends what you want to do, would "watches" work for you?  See number 4:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/15/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/